# Cant add ResourceDictionary to Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries from xamarin.forms

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms

I will explain in 3 basic steps what i do and then show the code:

1. I read an asset from android project (using xamarin.forms)
2. I receiv the textcontent to the multiplattform project where i want to use MVVM
   i then write the content to System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal folder
3. I want to add it to  Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries by using an new uri from the text i wrote in step 2.

The problem- when i try to add it to the ResourceDictionary it says - : 'Source can only be set from XAML.'

Code:

1)

```
            string content;
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(Assets.Open(assetName)))
        {
            content = sr.ReadToEnd();
        }
```

2. `

   ```
    private static string fileName { get; set; }
    public static void BeforeLoadForms(string colorsXAML)
    {
    var backingFile = 
    Path.Combine(System.Environment.GetFolderPath
    (System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), "colorsXAML.xaml");
    using (var writer = File.CreateText(backingFile))
    {
         writer.WriteLine(colorsXAML);
    }

    fileName = backingFile;
    }`
   ```
3. 

```
            Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Clear(); 
            ResourceDictionary rd1 = new ResourceDictionary();
            rd1.Source = new Uri(fileName, UriKind.Absolute);

        Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(rd1);
```

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve Can you explain ? or give me an example - not sure how you mean should do it? Setter like property {set;} ?

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve Thanks for your comment, but i think you missundstand me - the problem is that i want to load the resource from the file - and when i try do to that i get the error.

Comment: I thought the problem occurred on the last line of snippet 3. Are you saying the error occurs on the line `rd1.Source = ...`?

Comment: Unless you are following some code example, I believe that error message is a hint that it doesn't work this way. I don't think you can populate a dictionary from a URI. I think you need to build a dictionary yourself, adding the key-value pairs in code, then do `Application.Current.Resources = myDictionary;`  OR `Application.Current.Resources.Add(myDictionary);`.

Comment: @Niklas From [ResourceDictionary](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Core/ResourceDictionary.cs), you can try to use `SetAndLoadSource`  which is marked as For internal use by Xamarin Platform. Taking a look :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63009791/xamarin-forms-use-different-resource-dictionaries-for-different-build-configurat

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve yes i was unclear im sorry for that.

Comment: I didn't make a comment about clearness. You may have to build the dictionary yourself; e.g. use XML reader and methods to parse the file, add key/value pairs to a dictionary.

Comment: ... unless can get it to work via XAML. I've added an answer that attempts to do so.

Answer (score 0):

(Untested; I don't know if this will work.)

The error message says you can only set Source in XAML. First, try a manual test, where you use a file you've prepared beforehand.

Add to project a new item, a XAML file. Contents:

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
    x:Class="MyNameSpace.MyResourceDictionary" Source="file:///myresources.xml"/>
```

Put in appropriate names in place of MyNameSpace, MyResourceDictionary, myresources.xml.

I'm not sure the exact form needed for a file URI.

Then in your code, where you currently try to add to Resources.MergedDictionaries, instead do:

```
var rd = new MyResourceDictionary();
Application.Current.Resources = rd;
```

If you can get this to work, then you can improve it. For example, could use MVVM, change to `Source="{Binding ResourcesURI}"`.